# Selenium Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://192.168.1.34:62334/wd/hub

Tags: angularjs, selenium, npm

I'm reading a book (angularjs: novice to ninja) and after execute the following commands and installations:

```
npm install karma
npm install jasmine
npm install karma-chome-launcher
npm install protractor
```

then I try to run the following test:

```
sh scripts/test.sh 
sh scripts/e2e-test.sh
```

but sh scripts/e2e-test.sh gave me the following error:

```
Updating WebDriver
scripts
-------------------------------------------------------------------
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

Starting Protractor tests
scripts
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

/Users/Jean/repos/angularjsbook/chapter1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1761
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://192.168.1.34:62334/wd/hub
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at onResponse (/Users/Jean/repos/angularjsbook/chapter1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:87:11)
    at /Users/Jean/repos/angularjsbook/chapter1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:42:21
    at /Users/Jean/repos/angularjsbook/chapter1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/http/http.js:96:5
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/Jean/repos/angularjsbook/chapter1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:145:7)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1552:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

And I can't find anything on the forum of the book. Some help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to installed java from this link: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US because, Apple does not allow to install java from www.java.com

Answer (score 0):

Probably, when chrome web driver was downloaded on 'npm run update-webdriver' and cursor was just blinking for few extended secs, you might have terminated the batch job thinking that it has ended and thereafter running protractor started giving this problem.

One simple way is recreate everything from start,as i am not sure if uninstalling the webdriver will have some other issues with installed chrome browser.